# How to get the textbox value which is dynamically added to a table row inside a <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending a `<td>` having an input text to a row. I want to get the value of this textbox and use it in another function.
Below is the code snippet :

```
row.append($('<td ><input type="text" value=' + item.Marks + ' size="10px" class="marks" id="txtmarks" maxlength="3"/></td>'));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get its value like `$("#txtmarks").val()` right?

Comment: No there is no identity

Comment: Please provide a js fiddle link to understand the problem exactly

Comment: how do you tring to get the value? Is there any button ?

Comment: I don't have any button i just want that text box value to do calculation

Comment: why not add all `item.Marks` value to a variable ? Provide the details hows your are appending and how do you want to retrieve.

Comment: Are you wanting a particular textbox in the table or all the textboxs?

Comment: @meena have you tried `$('.marks').each(function(i, item) { ....  });` Where `item` hold all input fields.

Comment: @jogesh_pi  No i didn't  tried

Comment: @meena try and let us know.

Comment: @jogesh_pi  i tried its not getting

Comment: @meena can you share hows you tried?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69789/discussion-between-jogesh-pi-and-meena).

Comment: you should explain more. There is an input ID over there and you have to get it via # selector. if otherwise, you can select latest TD in the certain TR. otherwise, give your full code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Split it in two statements:

```
var input = $("<input type="text" size="10px" class="marks" id="txtmarks" maxlength="3"/>").val(item.Marks);
var newRow = $('<td></td>').append(input);
row.append(newRow);
```

So, now you have a reference to your input, and the code looks much cleaner.